# if i moved a separated object the whole object are moved..why?

Tags: objects

I was working on an animation in Blender, and for it I was essentially breaking apart a joined mesh... however when I went to move those joined bits (I separated them using P) it worked, at first, then when I moved the animation along the whole object jumped to where I had moved the broken part...

Comment: How many keyframes are in  your file?  Please include a Blender screen capture to clarify you question.  Make sure you show your keyframes. You may want to see a tutorial regarding keyframes.

Comment: my question is not about key frames. i created a puzzle, and i want an animation on it.but if i select one jigsaw piece the all other pieces are moving.. already i separated the objects using (p - separation)

Comment: See the answer below.    I do not want to burden you with a Screen Capture request a second time, its just too much work.  Good Luck.⚙

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you didn't accidentally activated the Proportional Editing Tool :
[image]

The shortcut is <kbd>O</kbd>.